# XMPP Multi-User-Chat: Javascript client has no affiliation

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am building a Javascript XMPP client, that creates or joins an XMPP Multi User Chat. The XMPP-Server is Openfire and I use strophe.js and the plugin strophe.muc.js in the browser. This is how I join:

```
var connection = new Strophe.Connection(HTTPBIND);
connection.muc.join(
        roomJid,
        userName,
        onMessage,
        onPresence,
        onRoster
);
```

Now I am trying to use the affiliation flag of any user to decide further steps, so I take the roster object, that is provided by the strophe library via the onRoster callback like this:

```
onRoster: function (roster){
    console.log(roster);
    // do stuff
    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately all my joined js-user-objects have the affiliation 'none'. I think this can not be a server fault, since if I join that MUC with a regular XMPP client (Adium), the associated user-object will have the appropriate affiliation 'member'. No password or any other restriction is set on the server-side at that time.

So what does Adium do differently at joining that MUC and what do I have to do at join to make the JS client become a 'member', too?